# PHP imagecopyresampled() gives black image for some files in my PC

Tags: javascript, php, image, image-processing

I have a script for resizing and cropping images when I upload them to the server and it works great. But today I discovered that a specific image is pure black after I upload it. So I dragged it into Photoshop and to my surprise it thrown an error "Could not complete your request because an unknown or invalid JPEG marher type is found." but paint and photo viewer displays them well.

So, my question is:

How do I solve this? (Maybe some user has some images that are corrupted as well and he tries to upload them to the server), does PHP imagecopyresampled/imagejpeg has some custom parameters that cand eal with this.

I repeat the script is working great except for this particular image. (a .JPG)

Thank in advance!

CODE:

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, $offsetX, $offsetY, $new_width, $new_height, $smallerDim, $smallerDim);

imagejpeg($image_p, $rootDir.'/uploads/'.$userid.'/thumb/'.$name_of_photo, 80);`enter code here`
```

Comment: Those files must be `png` files...

Comment: Windows says and I quote "Type of file: JPG File (.jpg)"

Comment: All right. DO you want us to assume thing without seeing your code... ?

Comment: I know my script won't work for png files, but the image I have problems with shows up to be a .jpg.

Comment: How do one create/execute your code ?

Comment: THe user  uploads the image into an input and the file is sent to the server where it is processed. My guess is that the  file is a png but has .jpeg extension for some reason. Is there any way to "test" the image in php before processing it as png or jpg?

Comment: How about `MIME` type ?

Comment: This is what a website gave me about the file:  type: image/jpeg 
tmp_name: /tmp/php5ys7J3 
error: 0 
size: 20855 
Filename: /tmp/php5ys7J3
MIME type image/jpeg is allowed
Fileinfo: image/png is allowed
file: image/png is allowed
Detected MIME: image/png is allowed
MIME Crutch: application/octetstream is failed

Comment: did you fix your problem? if not.. can you post your image?

Comment: I solved it. The problem was the image was indeed a PNG file even if it had a JPG extension. So I modified the script so it determines the MIME type then uses imagefromjpeg or imgfrom png respectively.